# PySpark - Taking First Value of Sequences of 1 and 0

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I need to take the first `indicator` in a dataframe and create a new indicator for each group of IDs. There will be long sequences of 0's, but the first 1 of a sequence of 1's need to have a row called the `first_indicator`.

```
dataframe=spark.createDataFrame([("B2", "2019-11-19 12:07:38", 1), ("B2", "2019-11-19 12:24:25", 1), 
                          ("B2", "2019-11-19 12:37:58", 0), ("B2", "2019-11-19 12:55:08", 1),
                          ("B2", "2019-11-19 13:07:28", 1), ("B2", "2019-11-19 13:20:28", 0),
                          ("F9", "2020-02-02 13:06:36", 0), ("F9", "2020-02-02 13:21:37", 1), 
                          ("F9", "2020-02-02 13:36:38", 1), ("F9", "2020-02-02 13:45:32", 0),
                          ("F9", "2020-02-02 14:06:32", 1), ("F9", "2020-02-02 14:24:31", 1)], 
                          ["id", "date_time", "indicator"]).show()

+---+-------------------+---------+
| id|          date_time|indicator|
+---+-------------------+---------+
| B2|2019-11-19 12:07:38|        1|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:24:25|        1|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:37:58|        0|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:55:08|        1|
| B2|2019-11-19 13:07:28|        1|
| B2|2019-11-19 13:20:28|        0|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:06:36|        0|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:21:37|        1|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:36:38|        1|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:45:32|        0|
| F9|2020-02-02 14:06:32|        1|
| F9|2020-02-02 14:24:31|        1|
+---+-------------------+---------+
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
+---+-------------------+---------+---------------+
| id|          date_time|indicator|first_indicator|
+---+-------------------+---------+---------------+
| B2|2019-11-19 12:07:38|        1|              1|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:24:25|        1|              0|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:37:58|        0|              0|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:55:08|        1|              1|
| B2|2019-11-19 13:07:28|        1|              0|
| B2|2019-11-19 13:20:28|        0|              0|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:06:36|        0|              0|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:21:37|        1|              1|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:36:38|        1|              0|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:45:32|        0|              0|
| F9|2020-02-02 14:06:32|        1|              1|
| F9|2020-02-02 14:24:31|        1|              0|
+---+-------------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window to partition and order by the dataframe and then take a lag function to compare the previous value was 0 and current value is 1.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date_time')

df.withColumn('target', ((lag('indicator', 1, 0).over(w) == 0) & (col('indicator') == 1)).cast('int')).show()

+---+-------------------+---------+------+
| id|          date_time|indicator|target|
+---+-------------------+---------+------+
| B2|2019-11-19 12:07:38|        1|     1|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:24:25|        1|     0|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:37:58|        0|     0|
| B2|2019-11-19 12:55:08|        1|     1|
| B2|2019-11-19 13:07:28|        1|     0|
| B2|2019-11-19 13:20:28|        0|     0|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:06:36|        0|     0|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:21:37|        1|     1|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:36:38|        1|     0|
| F9|2020-02-02 13:45:32|        0|     0|
| F9|2020-02-02 14:06:32|        1|     1|
| F9|2020-02-02 14:24:31|        1|     0|
+---+-------------------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to group by 'id' and collect 'date_time' and 'indicator' together in a list, so you have something like:

```
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id|                           array                         |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
| B2|[(2019-11-19 12:07:38, 1), (2019-11-19 12:24:25, 1) ... ]|
| F9|[(2020-02-02 13:06:36, 0), (2020-02-02 13:21:37, 0) ... ]|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Next you can build your own UDF returning the records wich are the first indicators. In this UDF you are not dealing with dataframes so the algorithm to apply is more 'natural' to think about.